# Empty statement operator catch only number or alphabet

Tags: bash, perl, if-statement, awk

I have two files one of them have that data file1:

```
content
```

file2 is created with vi and I just put some enters and have two or three rows but still no data just content.

That is not working for me, when have rows added but no other thing.

```
if [ ! -s file2 ]
    print "file2 is empty"
else
    print "file2 has content"
fi
```

In that case is turn: file2 has content

The idea is to catch in that file if there any alphabet or number anything else like space or enter to be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(<file2)` instead to check zero-content file:

```
if [[ -z "$(<file2)" ]]; then
    print "file2 is empty"
else
    print "file2 has content"
fi
```

`[[ -z "$(<file2)" ]]` will only be true for zero content file or a file with only new lines,

Comment: If `file2` contains any whitespace *other* than trailing newlines, it will still show as having content.

Comment: Yes that's true @chepner but OP wrote entering enter multiple times in the question. I wasn't sure if spaces/tabs will also be considered no-content by OP or not.

Comment: " anything else like space or enter to be empty": I think it's possible for the "empty" file to contains lines with whitespace, but no other printable characters.

Comment: Alright, to take care of white spaces we can use `[[ -z "$(tr -d '[[:space:]]' < file2)" ]]` in above `if` condition.

Answer (score 5):

```
if perl -ne'exit 1 if /\S/' file ; then
   echo 'Only contains blank lines'
fi
```

Come to think of it, `grep` would also do the trick.

```
if ! grep -q '[^[:space:]]' file ; then
   echo 'Only contains blank lines'
fi
```

These are better than anubhava's solution because they consider lines containing only spaces and tabs to be blank lines. It's never a good idea to assign significance to trailing whitespace.

Comment: What are you talking about `they take input from STDIN if no argument is provided`. Anubhava's solution could take input from STDIN just as easily as these ?

Comment: @Jidder, Oh I see, you'd use `"$(command)"` instead of `"$(<file)"`. Fixed

Comment: @ikegami yep, i agree that it is better to take into account all space characters though :)

Comment: +1 for the grep solution, this is the right answer. I'd use `if grep -q '[[:graph:]]'` instead of `if ! grep -q '[^[:space:]]'` though to avoid the double negative.

Comment: Could also do `grep -q [[:graph:]] file && echo Content || echo no content`

Answer (score 1):

awk way

```
awk 'NF{x++}END{print x?"File has content":"File empty"}' file
```

You could also stop processing the file when content is found this way

```
awk 'x+=NF{exit}END{print x?"File has content":"File empty"}' file
```